# What countour can I use to evaluate this definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

How can I evaluate this integral:

$$ \oint \frac{e^{2azi}}{z(z^{2}+1)}dz $$

I tried a semicircle contour that spans all of the real line while avoiding zero, because it is to evaluate this definite integral:

$$ \int\frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x^{2}(x^{2}+1)}dx, $$
from negative infinity to infinity.

Comment: Write $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2(x^2+1)}\,dx=\frac12\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-e^{i2x}}{x^2(x^2+1)}\,dx$$

Comment: @MarkViola's tip is great but, if you're not _au fait_ with principal values, replace $1-\exp(2ix)$ with $1+2ix-\exp(2ix)$, then take the integral's real part.

Comment: And don't forget to enforce the substitution $2x\mapsto x$ so that you can enclose on the semicircle.

Comment: Oh why do I need to make the substitution ? And do you have any links to learn how to use principal values ?